# How to handle onclick on null pixel of PNG image in android?

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, png

I have a ImageView (or ButtonImage) with background is a PNG image. Problem is i want to handle Onlclick function, when i click (touch) on where null pixel of PNG image, this will not do anything.
Thank you!

Comment: So, you want to shape your image so that no click will occur on the transparent area?

Comment: yes, it is, i don't known how i can do that.

Comment: I guess you want somethig like [this](http://fancifulandroid.blogspot.it/2014/07/android-imageview-crop-mask-image-as.html).

Comment: I will try, thank for your help! I hope it will work.